OpenID Connect Query String Serialization - plus or space
The OpenID Connect specification states that "Query String Serialization" will follow application/x-www-form-urlencoded format and links to the W3C HTML 4 specification, which in turn refers to whatwg.org 1, whatwg.org 2 which says "URLSearchParams objects will percent-encode anything in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded percent-encode set, and will encode U+0020 SPACE as U+002B (+)."
This encoding practice for application/x-www-form-urlencoded where space is encoded "+" goes contrary to common URI encoding where space is encoded "%20" as discussed previously, e.g. here, here.  This confusion has obviously led to pain and suffering for many a programmer.
Does this mean that the examples in the OIDC specification are slightly misleading or even incorrect as they consistently encode "scope=openid%20profile%20email" as opposed to "scope=openid+profile+email"? Are these equally compliant alternatives or is the former or latter the only valid option? Thanks in advance for your feedback.

I understand it the same way you did

The general consensus amongst the OpenID Connect scholars is that authorization servers should accept both forms:
A. scope=openid+profile+email
B. scope=openid%20profile%20email

See also https://gitlab.com/openid/conformance-suite/-/issues/1165
